# Comprobar si todos los archivos se pueden leer por el usuario actual

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy creando un script en Ubuntu y no logro hacer que el script antes de comprobar los md5, me informe si los archivos son accesibles para el usuario actual.

El script debe generar el md5 de directorios o archivos, y quisiera que antes de generarlo, el script compruebe si todos los archivos del directorio y subdirectorios son accesibles para el usuario actual. En caso de no ser accesible, el script debe solicitar al usuario que lo ejecute como root y finaliza su ejecución.

**SOLUCIONADO - UPDATE:**

Finalmente lo logré hacer funcionar. Probé si el md5sum retornaba error o no y ahí descubrí que estaba retornando error. Por lo que evidentemente al no ocurrir error con `find`, no retornaba ningún código de error. Buscando encontré esto: [Can I make find return non-0 when no matching files are found?](https://serverfault.com/a/829314/500213) y me ayudó a resolverlo reemplazando `\;` por `+` al final de `find`.

Por otra parte `2> /dev/null` evita que se imprima el error de Permiso denegado y el `if [ "$?" != "0" ]` comprueba si el código de retorno no es igual a 0.

Buscando en el manual de find, no he entendido por qué hace esto ya que se especifica que al agregar `+` siempre devolverá `true`. Como se puede observar en este ejemplo que publico, agregando `+`, devuelve el retorno de `-exec`.

Acá publico el ejemplo con el problema solucionado:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

tempdirectory=/tmp

echo
echo "Escriba la carpeta o archivo que desea comprobar:"
echo
read input
echo
find "$input" -type f -exec md5sum {} + 2> /dev/null > $tempdirectory/archive.txt
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
   echo
   echo "Se han encontrado errores durante la lectura."
   echo
 else
   echo
   echo "No se han encontrado errores durante la lectura."
   echo
fi
exit
```

Comment: ¿ Te has planteado lo que pasaría si compruebas los permisos de un archivo y, antes de generar el MD5, los permisos cambiasen ? Ese no es el planteamiento correcto en sistemas multiusuario.

Comment: @Trauma La verdad que no me lo he planteado, aunque podría suceder, las probabilidades supongo que deben ser muy bajas. Aún así, ¿debería asegurarme que esto no ocurra pidiendo al usuario que ejecute el script como root en lugar de comprobar los permisos?

Comment: Yo me limitaría a generar el md5, y, si ocurre algún error, informaría al usuario. Si usas `bash`, basta con comprobar `[ "$?" != "0" ]`. Piensa que te pueden surgir infinidad de condiciones ... raras. Archivos o directorios que desaparezcan, que cambian sus permisos, que se crean nuevos ... es lo que tienen los sistemas multiusuario ... ¡ nunca te aburres ! :-)

Comment: @Trauma Estoy de acuerdo con usted. He creado un pequeño script para probarlo y parece ser que no funciona. Me aparece que el permiso se ha denegado (no debería aparecer al tener un archivo como salida) y parece ser que el resultado del if sea el acceso denegado o no, es el mismo.

Comment: @Trauma Muchas gracias por todo! Me fue muy útil descubrir que <code>$?</code> devolvía el código de retorno del último programa ejecutado. Finalmente lo he solucionado y publicado la solución por si a alguno le sirve.